# How can I use transaction for two tables?

Tags: c#

How can I use transaction for two tables?

For example, we have two tables (main and detail), when I insert one record in main table, may insert some record in detail with for loop (MORE THAN ONE RECORD). I need control two table with transaction on time.

Comment: The usual comments follow. What have you tried? What have you searched?

Answer (score 1):

Use a transaction on the connection:

```
IDbConnection someConnection = new ....
var transaction = someConnection.BeginTransaction(TransactionScope.Serializable);

try
{
    IDbCommand cmd = someConnection.GetCommand();
    cmd.Transaction = transaction;
    ...
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    foreach(var data in subdata)
    {
        IDbCommand subcmd = someConnection.GetCommand();
        subcmd.Transaction = transaction;
        ...
        subcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    ...
    transaction.Commit();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    transaction.Rollback();
}
```

On `Commit()`, all data will be written. On `Rollback()`, no single data row will be written. So if something happens when the sub data is written, you can roll back the entire transaction and nor to the `main` neither to the `detail` table data is written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction();
```

method, for start a transaction, then execute your queries in order to insert into desired tables, then call `transaction.Commit();`, and in case of exception, call `transaction.RollBack();`

considering sqlConnection is your database connection variable